# Socket.io .on(message) seems be delayed

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I have server code like (simplified)

```
setInterval(longFunction,30);
setInterval(longFunction,30);

function longFunction(){
 console.log("longFunction");
 doSomethingLong();
}
```

elsewhere in server code...

```
socket.on("message",function(){
 console.log("message");
})
```

Problem is that when I send message from client, I can see in server console many many new logs from longFunction and only then I can see log from message.

I want to process message event as soon as possible but it looks that server prefer processing of intervals even multiple times first.

Comment: because those `setInterval ` are running in `30ms` interval even before `doSomethingLong` is done, effectively queueing the CPU for multiple times before any socket message can reach and be processed by server?

Comment: but how can I fix it?

Comment: It depends on what your expected behaviour between `setInterval`,  `longFunction`, and weksocket is, need more context.

Comment: I want more priority for message event. If I have message event, process it and run timers later. I changed setInterval to setTimeout and it didn't help. Problem is probably that i have more timers so they run in loop and no other code can be executed.

Comment: Since javascript is single thread, if `doSomethingLong` is a long running sync function, it cannot be pause/broken in the middle of execution. However what you can od is check if any message event should be processed before running `doSomethingLong`, i.e. in where your `console.log("longFunction");` is now.

Comment: How can I check it? I don't want solve event in middle of doSomethingLong. I want solve event(s) after/before.

Comment: check it before `doSomethingLong()` ?

Comment: It's event. So it should be checked automatically. Can I check events manually?